# Redirect RDP connection from PHP script not subdomain

Tags: php, rdp

My question is pretty straight forward.  I have been using ddns.net to have a subdomain that redirects to my home server.  Now Im pretty sure the answer is no here but is there a way to use a URL like domain.com/server.php to connect to my home server via RDP?  I know RDP is using the A records from the subdomain in ddns.net but it would be nice to just have a PHP script where I can update the IP and not have to use ddns.net.  A simple PHP redirect isnt working.

Comment: PHP is typically used with the http protocol, which is completely incompatible with RPD. Certainly you _can_ use php to server / use ther protocols, but I cannot imagine that you a result for RDP that is anywhere near being usable / making sense. Also I did not understand how you want to replace the ddns usage with a script. You still somehow have to make the name resolution from your domain name to the current, dynamic IP address. The only easy thing to solve your annoyance with ddns probably is to simply use a fixed IP address instead of a dynamic one. Ask your provider!

Answer (score -2):

No.

> to have a subdomain that redirects to my home server

No. Ddns publish a DNS record which points to your home server. There is no redirection.

> is there a way to use a URL like domain.com/server.php

No. Presumably you have some idea what RDP is; have you ever been asked for a URL when using an RDP client?

> just have a PHP script where I can update the IP and not have to use ddns.net

You seem to be lacking a very basic understanding of how the internet works. There are some good tutorials on the internet; spending some time reading them might not answer your question but should equip you to ask questions that people can respond to with constructive advice.

Comment: I understand how the internet works.  I am currently using a subdomain to connect to rdp so youre wrong in saying it wouldnt work.  What im fuzzy on is how rdp works and whether it just looks at the A record or if theres a way to trick rdp into following a script response with an IP address.  Like a redirect header or something.